# How to run 2 thread in program

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Here is my code.I want achieve multithreading.I mean to say I want thread one to execute first.After some time whether thread 1 has completed task or not come back from that and execute thread 2.After some time move to thread one again.How to do that.I tried to join method here but no use.

```
private void ThreadCreate()
{
    try
    {                        
        Print  thr1 = new Print("First Thread : Service Started ");
        Print  thr2 = new Print("Seconf Thread : Service Started");

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thr1.TextLog));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thr2.TextLog));

        thread1.Name = "Thread1";
        thread2.Name = "Thread2";

        thread1.Start();              
        thread2.Start();

        thread1.Join(1000);
        thread2.Join(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

///// Part2 
class Print
{
    public string apppath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();    
    string _message;

    public Print(string message)
    {
        this_message = message;
    }

    public void TextLog()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw;
            FileInfo f;
            Thread thr = Thread.CurrentThread;
            int j = 0;


            string s = apppath + " Print " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt";

            f = new FileInfo(s);
            if (f.Exists)
            {
                sw = f.AppendText();
            }
            else
            {
                sw = f.CreateText();
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
            sw.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine(_msg + "    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff"));

            if (_msg == "Service Stopped ...............")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread thr2 = Thread.CurrentThread;
                    if (thr2.Name == "Thread1")
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(thr2.Name + " : " + i + "    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(thr2.Name + " ::: " + i + "    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff"));
                    }

                    j = j + 1;
                    sw.WriteLine("Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    sw.WriteLine("Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _message = e.Message;               
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting output like this.
OutPut:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
First Thread : Service Started     2018.08.28 12:32:10:1123
Thread1 : 0    2018.08.28 12:32:10:1123
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 1    2018.08.28 12:32:11:1279
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 2    2018.08.28 12:32:12:1436
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 3    2018.08.28 12:32:13:1593
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 4    2018.08.28 12:32:14:1750
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 5    2018.08.28 12:32:15:1907
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 6    2018.08.28 12:32:16:2063
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 7    2018.08.28 12:32:17:2220
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 8    2018.08.28 12:32:18:2377
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 9    2018.08.28 12:32:19:2534
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
First Thread : Service Started     2018.08.28 12:33:00:1499
Thread1 : 0    2018.08.28 12:33:00:1499
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 1    2018.08.28 12:33:01:1656
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 2    2018.08.28 12:33:02:1813
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 3    2018.08.28 12:33:03:1969
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping --------------------------------------
```

Here thread one executed first and thread 1 start.I don't output like this.

Expected output :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
First Thread : Service Started     2018.08.28 12:32:10:1123
Thread1 : 0    2018.08.28 12:32:10:1123
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 1    2018.08.28 12:32:11:1279
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 2    2018.08.28 12:32:12:1436
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread2 : 0    2018.08.28 12:32:13:1593
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread2 : 1    2018.08.28 12:32:14:1750
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 3    2018.08.28 12:32:15:1907
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread1 : 4    2018.08.28 12:32:16:2063
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread2 : 2    2018.08.28 12:32:17:2220
Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can use `Task` and `ContinueWith` [ContinueWith(Action<Task>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__)

Comment: Multi threading is a means rather than an end. Your description is unclear in that it seems to describe a process that does not perform tasks concurrently even though you want them in different threads. Are they allowed to run at the same time or must the first task abort before the second can commence? Also, your logging code is very much not threadsafe. They will contend around the file stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the output log, there are about 50 seconds between your "Service started" events. I think they come from two different runs of your application.

Another thing is why you don't get any output from Thread2. That's because your Thread1 have got an exclusive access to the log file. Thread2 tries to access the file, gets an exception (IOException) as the file is in use, but there is no way to log this exception, so the thread quietly dies.

If you want to write information into your log from multiple threads, you need to synchronize your file access. I would suggest creating a special class for that. Something like (the simplest possible, demonstration purposes only):

```
public static class Log1
{
    private static string filePath;
    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void WriteLine(string m)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test20");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, "Print_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt");
            }
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, m + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your thread method turns into:

```
    public void TextLog()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread thr = Thread.CurrentThread;
            int j = 0;

            Log1.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            Log1.WriteLine(_message + "    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff"));

            if (_message == "Service Stopped ...............")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread thr2 = Thread.CurrentThread;
                    if (thr2.Name == "Thread1")
                    {
                        Log1.WriteLine(thr2.Name + " : " + i + "    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log1.WriteLine(thr2.Name + " ::: " + i + "    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff"));
                    }

                    j = j + 1;
                    Log1.WriteLine("Thread will sleep now -----------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Log1.WriteLine("Thread came out from sleeping -----------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _message = e.Message;
            Log1.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Which effectively produces something like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Seconf Thread : Service Started    2018.08.28 10:27:19:8441
Thread2 ::: 0    2018.08.28 10:27:19:8491
Thread will sleep now         
-----------------------------------------------------------------
First Thread : Service Started     2018.08.28 10:27:19:8402
Thread1 : 0    2018.08.28 10:27:19:8691
Thread will sleep now    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread came out from sleeping     
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Thread2 ::: 1    2018.08.28 10:27:20:8665
Thread will sleep now 
...
```

Comment: Thanks rs232 for your help.Your code helped me lot.